# Receive bluetooth signal when bluetooth is switched off in the device

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I am developing a new Android/IOS app which is going to use BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) Beacons. So the plan is to receive a beacon signal and do something with it.

What I want to know is, how can I receive the signal when bluetooth is switched off in the device?

Comment: So how far you are ? like have you tried any codes?

Comment: Without turnon bluetooth its not possible to detect beacons

Comment: I am about to create a concept for the app. And before I begin to code, I want to evaluate if the concept is possible at all.

Comment: ok thats great you can read about BLE in android developer so that You can starting great from its docs

Answer (score 0):

Both android and iOS devices are in control of their Bluetooth connections. There is no way to override Bluetooth being off and send and receive any signals at all. This is due mainly to battery concerns. Both apple and Google want the user to be in control of that function.

Comment: This is not correct. At least on Android devices one can enable bluetooth through the app: [bluetooth API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).
But I need bluetooth to be turned on when the device is nearby a beacon.